# Linking Up Google Sheets and Google Calendar

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to get work shifts that are created in a Google Sheet to be automatically entered into each individual employees Google Calendar.

Here is a link to a test Google Sheet (accessible by anyone with the link): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJKwZmHaVesBA6xRxKwWEuiZVtfGfAKdK9sI39on95g/edit?usp=sharing

I assume I can enter some code into a google script, but I am not a programmer, so I have no clue where to begin - if this is even possible.

Here is a brief description of what you are seeing in the Google Sheet:

Each person has 2 weeks of shifts that run from left to right. 
Each letter represents a different shift, with the corresponding day at the top.
I would need a separate email associated with Person1, Person2, etc.

I would really appreciate any help! If you have any questions at all, just ask!

Thanks,

Cory

Comment: Do you need to access each employees calender separately?  Or can you enter all the events into a master calender, and invite each employee to the event?  Are you adding calender events manually now?

Comment: If you want, take a look at my profile, and send me an email.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy. I have sent you an email!

Answer (score 1):

You would need permission to access all these people's calender's.  They can grant permission when the code runs.  If the user has more than one calender, and you don't want the program to change/use the default calender, then you'd need to know the name of the calender that they want updated. All the information in your spreadsheet would need to be "parsed".

Basically, you need to get the data out of the spreadsheet.  You will use `getValues()` for that.  That returns a two dimensional array.  So, you need to be able to use a FOR loop with a two dimensional array.  The code to put a new event into a calender shouldn't be that hard relatively.  Just search the documentation, and there will be example code.

[Google Documentation - Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))